# вывод нескольких массивов из отфильтрованного многомерного массива

Tags: php, json

Имеется массив данного типа,длина не ограничена

```
array (size=3)
  'code' => int 200
  'message' => null
  'data' => 
    array (size=2)
      'data' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=34)
              'outage_id' => string '47416928' (length=8)
              'outage_root_id' => string '47416928' (length=8)
              'address_list' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'Стрельбищенский переулок, дом 22, строение 1' (length=78)
              'address_list_raw' => 
                array (size=1)
                  1541016 => 
                    array (size=2)
                      'floors' => 
                        array (size=0)
                          empty
                      'outage_object_id' => 
                        array (size=1)
                          'outage_object' => null
              'outage_kind_name' => string 'Плановое отключение' (length=37)
              'outage_kind_id' => string '20' (length=2)
              'outage_reason_name' => string 'Установка узлов учета воды (ХВС)' (length=58)
              'outage_type_id' => string '568' (length=3)
              'outage_type_name' => string 'Холодное водоснабжение (ХВС)' (length=52)
              'outage_reason_id' => string '1333' (length=4)
              'outage_reason_root_id' => string '1333' (length=4)
              'plan_date_off' => string '2020-01-13T06:00:31.000Z' (length=24)
              'fact_date_off' => string '2020-01-13T06:00:31.000Z' (length=24)
              'plan_date_on' => string '2020-01-13T09:00:31.000Z' (length=24)
              'fact_date_on' => string '2020-01-13T09:00:31.000Z' (length=24)
              'note' => string '' (length=0)
              'initiator_org_name' => string 'АО "Мосводоканал"' (length=31)
              'initiator_org_id' => string '489367' (length=6)
              'tp' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'ctp' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'ctp_tp' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'create_date' => string '2020-01-10T11:13:59.877Z' (length=24)
              'create_date_ui' => string '10.01.2020 14:13' (length=16)
              'creator_fio' => null
              'delete_reason' => null
              'is_deleted' => boolean false
              'bti_okrug_name_list' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
              'bti_district_name_list' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'Пресненский' (length=22)
              'district' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'Пресненский' (length=22)
              'okrug' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
              'bti_okrug_list_id' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string '1499174' (length=7)
              'bti_district_list_id' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string '1499299' (length=7)
              'bpm_operation' => null
              'bpm_except' => null
          1 => 
            array (size=34)
              'outage_id' => string '47416715' (length=8)
              'outage_root_id' => string '47416715' (length=8)
              'address_list' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'улица Жуковского, дом 11' (length=42)
              'address_list_raw' => 
                array (size=1)
                  1536134 => 
                    array (size=2)
                      'floors' => 
                        array (size=0)
                          empty
                      'outage_object_id' => 
                        array (size=1)
                          'outage_object' => null
              'outage_kind_name' => string 'Аварийное отключение' (length=39)
              'outage_kind_id' => string '19' (length=2)
              'outage_reason_name' => string 'Неисправность на сетях теплоснабжения' (length=71)
              'outage_type_id' => string '571' (length=3)
              'outage_type_name' => string 'Центральное отопление (ЦО)' (length=48)
              'outage_reason_id' => string '1309' (length=4)
              'outage_reason_root_id' => string '1309' (length=4)
              'plan_date_off' => string '2020-01-10T10:04:31.000Z' (length=24)
              'fact_date_off' => string '2020-01-10T10:04:31.000Z' (length=24)
              'plan_date_on' => string '2020-01-17T14:00:00.000Z' (length=24)
              'fact_date_on' => null
              'note' => string 'Замена уч-ка трубы ЦО в подвале .' (length=58)
              'initiator_org_name' => string 'ГБУ «ЖИЛИЩНИК БАСМАННОГО РАЙОНА»' (length=61)
              'initiator_org_id' => string '62751' (length=5)
              'tp' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'ctp' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'ctp_tp' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'create_date' => string '2020-01-10T11:11:26.790Z' (length=24)
              'create_date_ui' => string '10.01.2020 14:11' (length=16)
              'creator_fio' => null
              'delete_reason' => null
              'is_deleted' => boolean false
              'bti_okrug_name_list' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
              'bti_district_name_list' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'Басманный' (length=18)
              'district' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'Басманный' (length=18)
              'okrug' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
              'bti_okrug_list_id' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string '1499174' (length=7)
              'bti_district_list_id' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string '1499203' (length=7)
              'bpm_operation' => null
              'bpm_except' => null
          2 => 
            array (size=34)
              'outage_id' => string '47416370' (length=8)
              'outage_root_id' => string '47416172' (length=8)
              'address_list' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'Комсомольский проспект, дом 45' (length=54)
              'address_list_raw' => 
                array (size=1)
                  1810710 => 
                    array (size=2)
                      'floors' => 
                        array (size=0)
                          empty
                      'outage_object_id' => 
                        array (size=1)
                          'outage_object' => null
              'outage_kind_name' => string 'Аварийное отключение' (length=39)
              'outage_kind_id' => string '19' (length=2)
              'outage_reason_name' => string 'Неисправность на сетях ХВС' (length=49)
              'outage_type_id' => string '568' (length=3)
              'outage_type_name' => string 'Холодное водоснабжение (ХВС)' (length=52)
              'outage_reason_id' => string '1307' (length=4)
              'outage_reason_root_id' => string '1307' (length=4)
              'plan_date_off' => string '2020-01-10T11:05:51.000Z' (length=24)
              'fact_date_off' => string '2020-01-10T11:05:51.000Z' (length=24)
              'plan_date_on' => string '2020-01-10T13:00:34.000Z' (length=24)
              'fact_date_on' => null
              'note' => string 'После сварочных работ,течь возобновилась.' (length=77)
              'initiator_org_name' => null
              'initiator_org_id' => null
              'tp' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'ctp' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'ctp_tp' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'create_date' => string '2020-01-10T11:05:51.767Z' (length=24)
              'create_date_ui' => string '10.01.2020 14:05' (length=16)
              'creator_fio' => null
              'delete_reason' => null
              'is_deleted' => boolean false
              'bti_okrug_name_list' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
              'bti_district_name_list' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'Хамовники' (length=18)
              'district' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'Хамовники' (length=18)
              'okrug' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
              'bti_okrug_list_id' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string '1499174' (length=7)
              'bti_district_list_id' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string '1499180' (length=7)
              'bpm_operation' => null
              'bpm_except' => null
```

Написал функцию которая парсит заявки только с определенного района

```
function parser(){
include 'request.php';
$data = json_decode($json , true);
$avarii = $data['data']['data'];
    foreach ($avarii as $item) {
        if (isset($item['bti_district_name_list'][0]) && $item['fact_date_on'] == null && $item['bti_district_name_list'][0] == 'Тверской') {
            echo $item['bti_district_name_list'][0] . '<br>';
            echo $item['outage_kind_name'] . '<br>';
            echo $item['outage_reason_name'] . '<br>';
            echo $item['outage_type_name'] . '<br>';
            echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($item['plan_date_off'])) . '<br>';
            echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($item['plan_date_on'])) . '<br>';
            echo $item['note'] . '<br>';
            echo '<br>';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Задача как записать цикл чтобы парсились последние 3 таких заявок и отображались пока не появятся новые.Прошу не пинать за кривой код,учусь только)

Comment: а массив из базы?

Comment: а так накапиливаешь в массив $go[]=$item['bti_district_name_list'][0]; print_r($go);  и потом есть сравнивание массивов https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php

Comment: массив из GET запроса к API